# How to form better version of one particular setence

Tags: grammar, sentence

I need to say
"For those who feel the below post pin points you, it is not coincidental or unintentional. It IS JUST meant for you"

Is there a better way I can frame above sentence. I want to share some content where people judge new moms and what I want to put as a intro statement is the above line.

Comment: Please don't use *below* as a pre-positive adjective. Use "the post below". *Pinpoints* is one word. Apart from that, what are you unhappy with? If you ask a **specific** question about a **specific** word or two and explain why you're uncertain about that, your question might be reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one way to put the above sentence is

> For those who feel the below post pinpoints you, IT DOES, it is
>   intentional and not coincidental. It IS JUST meant for you.